# number of zeroes to prefix file number

Tags: python

The point of this is to find number of zeroes to put in new file names.
Say, if there is 86 files in dir, we need to start file names from 00 (or 01), if there's 600, 001, etc.

```
dir_ls = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

# number of zeroes to prefix file number
ln = len(str(len(dir_ls))) - 1
```

Is it all right, or this can be done better?
This double conversion feels stupid.

Comment: With `math.log10` you can do it without converting to string.

Comment: IMHO using a long enough **fix** prefix length simplifies your program and does not degrade readability of files names.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import math
>>> int(math.ceil(math.log10(86)))
2
>>> int(math.ceil(math.log10(600)))
3
```

Comment: probably its not worth to import math.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you are doing right thing at all.

If you are going to place files numbered with a string like `'%03.d' % num` you will not get that you want in described way.

Say if you already have 99 files in your directory then their names will start from `01` and end with `99`. Then you will create file named `100` and from now on you will try to name your files from `001` to `999`. And you can get the situation when their will be both `01` and `001` files in the same time. I don't think that this is what you want.

I suggest to chose sane number of zeros before you start to numbering your files and never change this.

It is a good idea to choose `6` digits numbers and create the number string with the pattern `%06.d` as this will let you create much more than `100 000` different files in one dir and when you reach this number of files you will need to save them in separate folders to decrease filesystem seek times thus you will never need more than that.

*Additionally it is easier to pronounce and remember 6 digits numbers than 5 or 7 digits numbers.*